# Wouldn't it be easy to find private keys with the Diffie Hellman exchange?

Tags: cryptography

I recently watched [this video](https://youtu.be/NmM9HA2MQGI) by Computerphile, where Mike explains the mathematics of the Diffie Hellman exchange. I've been wondering, since as explained $g$, $g^a$ and $g^b$ is public, can't you just do this equation
$$
\frac{1}{log_{(g^a)}(g)} = a
$$
and $$
\frac{1}{log_{(g^b)}(g)} = b
$$
to find their private keys? I might be dumb, please explain this.

Comment: I believe the important part is that it is $\bmod p$ for some prime $p$, hence log won’t exactly function.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/why-is-the-discrete-logarithm-problem-assumed-to-be-hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the discrete log is the hard part. Remember that the logarithms are taking place in the group, not the real numbers.